# Is it possible to replace random url with nginx substring

Tags: nginx, substring, proxypass

i have this kind of random string url using nginx substring

http://example.com/-UJ7GGXX5bo3w/ZnpPtIWiABs/TTTXIANZk/dHNEIuFjucvd7RiwwCLcBchJiIwIi8jGAmOrvyxs

i have successfully use proxy_pass to the domain name and i need to change the random url parts to become something like this

http://example.com/directory1/directory2/directory/directory4

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `regex` in the location like

```
location ~ ^/[0-9a-zA-Z]+/[0-9a-zA-Z]+/[0-9a-zA-Z]+/[0-9a-zA-Z]+$ {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/directory1/directory2/directory/directory4;
}
```